# prevent refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

looked trought alot but cant find the solution to my problem, can someone please tell me why this isnt working?

```
if(titeln == 0 || grades == 0 || imdblink == 0 || bilden == 0 || handlingen == 0)
        {
            alert("Please fill out the form correctly");    
            $('form[name=test]').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            });
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
```

if you fill out the form correct the first time it submits perfectly but if you left som textarea empty the function preventDefault runs as it should, then you correct the problem and fill it out  the function still runs when you press submit? why does the function keep running even if the fields have been corrected?

Comment: What do you mean "keep running"? Were you expecting the validation to magically only apply the first time around?

Comment: i thougt the if statements would run again after I clicked submit and that it would not get stuck at the same place again because none of the fields is equal to 0, but apperantly it doesnt...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are binding it again!

All you need to do in your above code is to return `false` on encountering any error.

i.e.

```
if(titeln == 0 || grades == 0 || imdblink == 0 || bilden == 0 || handlingen == 0)
{
    alert("Pleae fill out the form correctly"); 
    return false;
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try put in else clause

```
$('form[name=test]').submit();
```